# How to clean a particular directory before each build starts in jenkins?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, integration, jenkins

I am using **jenkins** with **hudson cli** through java. I **want clean a particular directory** before each build. Any idea ?  I have provided the maven command **clean package** which clean target folder for each build. What i want is i want to clean some other directory before each build. How to do this ?

In **jenkins** i specified **URL of maven project** , Which ll **download  files to workspace** when building. When i give **clean package command**, it **clears target** folder every time when building. There is **another folder parallel to target folder**. i want to **clear** that **folder which is inside maven project**.

Comment: Which directory - is it directly related to your build (workspace, artifacts, etc.), totally unrelated, or semi-related (i.e. keyed by parameters in your build, build_id, etc.)?

Comment: i have added more information. Thanks.

Comment: Will @BrandonV's solution work for you? If not - please clarify why not.

Comment: @kaleeswaran14 - Can you please update and / or mark the answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer, again, to correspond to your new requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pom.xml add the profile tag like below

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ci</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
<id>default-clean</id>
<phase>pre-clean</phase>
<goals>
    <goal>clean</goal>
</goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<fileset>
    <directory>do_not_checkin/build</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
                              </includes>
    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                          </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

While executing commad just execute the maven command `mvn -Pci clean`.

Which uses the maven clean plugin to clear a particular directory, before each build starts.

We can package like **`mvn -Pci clean package`**.

After cleaning the directory , package phase is executed.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running version 1.433 or higher, use the **Pre Steps** / **Post Steps** in the project configuration section, located above and below the **Build** section, respectively.

Otherwise, install the [M2 Extra Steps Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Extra+Steps+Plugin).

You can configure the [maven-clean-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) to handle the cleaning.

If you can't modify your pom.xml, as stated below, you can also use this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin).

Comment: I tried it. I don't know how to do this ? Maven project's different folder has to be deleted every time before build starts.

Comment: What did you try?  You can't just use a batch / shell command?

Please don't un-mark an answer without explaining why.

Comment: In my maven project while build is generated target folder  is cleared and regenerated again. Before each build starts in jenkins , i want to clean/delete a directory. So that in Presteps, i used shell command to clear a directory . It works fine for Mac machine, it is not working for windows machine. I want to clean/delete a directory without machine dependent code. Is there any other way ?

Comment: You can configure the [maven-clean-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) to do this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I can't do any modification in pom.xml, i need someother way to clean the directory from jenkins itself.

Comment: You can't add a plugin to the pom.xml?  These are things you should be stating in your initial question.

In that case, look at this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) to do exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a JOB to clean the directory you want before each build. I have used ANT for this, no idea about MAVEN. This will not be machine dependent as well.

Comment: Care to elaborate on this old post?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if you are using repository to poll for changes and before each new build you do pull all files project from repo you could just use one of the options called: "Emulate clean checkout by first deleting..." This way all folders should be deleted before each build.

If that is not the case the most simple answer that comes into my mind is simply to write a CMD script which does simply DEL command on unwanted files/directories and run it as a pre step or post step as windows batch command.